# How to get programmatically the Web browser's IP address and Port number in C#?

Tags: c#, http-proxy

I am creating a **Http proxy** that seats between the web browser and the web server and based on my requirements the proxy server should get the **IP address** and **port number** of the **web browser** that has made a request. Here is a class that represent the connection between the proxy and web browser.

```
  public class Client
  {
    public Client(IPAddress browserIP, int browserPort)
    {
       /*Use browserIP and browserPort to create a socket object*/
    }
  }
```

Note that i am not using  neither **HttListener** nor **HttpRequest** objects! I have created a custom **Request** object that allows me to set the http headers and other stuff that the HttpRequest object doesn't do;but my Request object doesn't have a method to get the browser IP address and Port.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [class](http://www.triconsole.com/dotnet/httprequest_class.php)

You can use the Request object to get the IP of the requesting end.

```
string remoteAddr = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

EDIT: That'll get you the Hostname. good enough to get started with!

Comment: How about the browser port number?

Answer (score 1):

```
  string  ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
                ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Try the above. it fetches the ip of the requesting client.